# Creating an Outlook rule in C#, in particular using the toOrFromRuleCondition.Recipients.Count property

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have seen the examples on writing Outlook rules but I am having trouble with the toOrFromRuleCondition.Recipients.Count property. My rule has to do with moving messages with over a certain number of recipients.  I don't know how to instantiate that

```
  Outlook.Rule rule = null;
  rule = rules.Create("Jeff", Outlook.OlRuleType.olRuleReceive);
  Outlook.RuleCondition ruleConditions = rule.Conditions.ToOrCc;
  ruleConditions.Enabled = true;


  Outlook.ToOrFromRuleCondition toOrFromRuleCondition = ?? what do I put here??;
  toOrFromRuleCondition.Enabled = true;

  if (toOrFromRuleCondition.Recipients.Count > 5)
      // do action on this message...
```

Comment: Why do you need to create rules programmatically instead of handling all of that in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating rules in VBA you can handle the [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event of the `Application` class. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. Use the Entry ID  to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

So, in the `NewMailEx` event handler you could check the number of recipients and do whatever you need to.

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    Dim item as Object 
Set item = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection)
End Sub
```

Comment: Great suggestion as I have determined there is no way to discover the count of recipients inside a rule (the class exposes only what is in the rule wizard and that ability doesn't exist in the rule wizard).  Thanks!!!

Comment: Yeah, if you can't set up something in the rules wizard - you can't do that programmatically.

Comment: It makes sense to mark the answer if it helped.

Comment: Any chance you have any sample code for that event? I did a search and surprisingly didn't find anything useful.  Sorry new to this, not sure how to mark it answered, should be obvious like a button "Answered" :-)

Comment: I've added a piece of code which shows how to get the item received.